# How can I change quantity for a specific article in my basket?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in dev, and my first solo project is almost finish but ...

My question is: I have a basket with articles and I want to increase or decrease the quantity just for one article.

Do I have to have a state by article ?

Here is my code:

```
const handleClickDecrease =(position) =>{
    console.log(position) 
    if(articleQuantity>1){
     setArticleQuantity(articleQuantity-1)
 }
}
 
const handleClickIncrease =(position) =>{
    console.log(position)
    setArticleQuantity(articleQuantity+1)
}



var basket=[];
for(let i=0; i<basketArticleTab.length;i++){
    basket.push(<Row className="newArticle">
                    <img className='articleImg' src={basketArticleTab[i].picture}></img><h3 className="newArticleTitle">{basketArticleTab[i].name}</h3><h3 className="newArticleTitle"><Button class="less" variant="dark" onClick={()=>handleClickDecrease(basketArticleTab[i])} >-</Button>{' '}{articleQuantity}<Button variant="dark" onClick={()=>handleClickIncrease()}>+</Button>{' '}</h3><h3 className="newArticleTitle">Price H.T</h3><h3 className="newArticleTitle">{basketArticleTab[i].priceHT}</h3><img onClick={()=>handleClickTrash(basketArticleTab[i]._id)} className='deleteIcon' src='trash.svg' alt='delete item'></img>
                </Row>)
}
```

and my state :

```
const [articleQuantity, setArticleQuantity] = useState(1);
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. *Do I have to have a state by article?*: Yes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer !! 
How am I suppose to define my states if I don't know which article will be selected in the basket ?

Comment: Your quantity state can e.g. be an object where the keys are unique ids that identify an article and the values are the amounts in the basket. When a user adds an article (e.g. by clicking a button) you increase the amount using the article id of the article that was clicked on.